# best way to empty and reset tables in phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I almost done with my website but I have a question.
Im using phpmyadmin and I need to reset my database AND WITHOUT LOOSING INDEXES : empty all tables and reset all ids.

Whats the best way to do it??

Thank you

Comment: Check all tables and hit truncate?

Comment: Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`memoire`.`theater`, CONSTRAINT `theater_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cinema_id`) REFERENCES `memoire`.`cinema` (`cinema_id`))

Comment: If you have constraints like that and don't feel like truncating things in the right order (or having cascading deletes) then you may as well drop the DB and re-populate the structure.